# jQuery: Move div across pages/url's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

Is it possible to animate a div, or any other `HTML` element on a page refresh using jQuery or a similar web technology?

---

I am thinking something like the [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com/) search box animation.
When clicking the input, the element remains, while the rest of the page fades out and the `URL` changes. Then the new elements fade in.

---

This has to be possible by telling the browser somehow that an element should remain on the page after a request and providing the information, that it is the same as the other element loaded with the request.

Comment: Google Photos is an SPA - single page application.  It doesn't actually navigate to another page.   Google have got `window.history.pushState` down to a fine art.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the combination of two things:

1. Typical animation (you can do that with jQuery by adding classes and leave animation to CSS or use jQuery Animations https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp)
2. History API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) you can manipulate with URL

Comment: So it's not possible to persist certain elements after a GET request has been made?

Comment: You can show/animate DOM elements based on URL even without jQuery. More informations you'll find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/get-current-url-in-javascript)